# UltraGrid table filtering: Can I store and recall the filter settings to a database?

Tags: c#, filter, save, ultrawingrid

I have an ultragrid datatable that has two or three columns that will be changed often depending on who is looking at the report.  I was wondering if it is possible to store the filter so that if a person wanted status -> paid, date ->today, status -> unsent as the filter it could be a predetermine one click instead of setting each field?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by saving the UltraGrid layout. The below example saves the layout to a file, but you can as well use that to save it in the database record.

Try to mess around with PropertyCategories, but be careful not to save the data on the grid along.

```
    private void btnSaveLayout_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        // show dialog to choose file
        if ( saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog ( this ) == DialogResult.OK ) {
            // open file stream
            System.IO.FileStream fileLayout = new System.IO.FileStream ( saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate );
            // reset position
            fileLayout.Seek ( 0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin );
            // write layout
            this.ultraGrid.DisplayLayout.Save ( fileLayout,
                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.AppearanceCollection
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.ColumnFilters
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.Groups
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.SortedColumns
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.Summaries
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.ColScrollRegions
            );
            // close stream
            fileLayout.Close ();
        }
    }

    private void btnLoadLayout_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        // show dialog to choose file
        if ( openFileDialog1.ShowDialog ( this ) == DialogResult.OK ) {
            // open file stream
            System.IO.FileStream fileLayout = new System.IO.FileStream ( openFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open );
            // reset position
            fileLayout.Seek ( 0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin );
            // load layout
            this.ultraGrid.DisplayLayout.Load ( fileLayout,
                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.AppearanceCollection
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.ColumnFilters
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.Groups
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.SortedColumns
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.Summaries
                | Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.ColScrollRegions
            );
            // close stream
            fileLayout.Close ();
        }
    }
```

You might also consider having a check in the SaveLayout method, to make sure there is actually any data inside the grid, before you commit the layout save.